# How do I show errors in Junit XML from jest tests?

Tags: javascript, xml, junit, jestjs

I have a Jest test file. 
When I have no errors in my code in my Junit log.xml it shows errors="0".
But when I have syntax errors my log file becomes empty. It just shows an empty test suite.

In PHP unit when you have a syntax error it generates a **error** With the syntax error.

How do I also generate that **error** tag in a jest log? I'm doing this because I have to print the syntax errors somewhere.
Failures tag is when a test fails. When does a error tag appear?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using the [jest-junit](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-junit) plugin?

From version `v12.0.0` onwards, you can make syntax errors appear in your `junit.xml` output if you set `"reportTestSuiteErrors": "true"` as a configuration option.

```js
  "jest-junit": {
    "outputDirectory": "./target/test-reports/",
    "reportTestSuiteErrors": "true"
  }
```